# CSS3 - Sticky position not work

Tags: html, css

i'm try to create navigation menu under header section with *sticky* positioning but i can't get it work, here my css code :

```
    body{

}
header{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index:100;
}
    #logo{
        position: relative;
        height: 85px;
        width: 120px;
        /*border: 1px solid black;*/
        float: left;
        background-image: url('logoArdi.svg');
        background-position: center;
        background-size: contain;
    }
    #judulWeb{
        position: relative;
        height: 85px;
        width: 200px;

        text-align: center;
        float: left;
    }
    #kontak{
        position: inherit;
        float: right;
        height: 100px;
        top: 20px;
        right: 10px;
    }
        .imghead{
            margin: auto 5px auto auto;
        }
    .sticky{
        position: sticky;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: -o-sticky;
        top: 0px;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        height:30px;
        background-color: #26282b;
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #26282b;
    }

        ul li{
            position:relative;
            bottom:11px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: auto 30px auto auto;
        }
        ul li{
            color:whitesmoke;

            /*background-color:black;
            border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
            padding: 5px;*/
        }
        ul li:hover{
            color:#26282b;
            background-color: whitesmoke ;
        }
    #kontak{
        position: inherit;
        float: right;
        height: 100px;
    }
#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    top: 132px;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
}
    .imgutama{
        width: 200px;
    }
```

i don't now the mistake, but i just intend to create page header and navigation, the navigation is below the page header and will stick on top even i scroll down.

note : navigation class is "sticky".

Comment: position:sticky work only in firefox and safari. (http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) This is not the best solution

Comment: then i'm stuck with javascript :) thanks for the link!

Comment: If you've resolved your problem, you can post the answer yourself and select it as the accepted answer. We don't do "SOLVED" in the title here.

Comment: I've just founded this solution http://jsfiddle.net/Nath/Ue7yT/ . It's very simply. Check it out. Maybe would be helpful to you.

Answer (score -1):

```
#sidebar {
    position: -webkit-sticky;  // required for Safari
    position: sticky;
    top: 0; // required as well.
}
```

Comment: Your answer is (yet) not helpful. There is no #sidebar in the question